# When migrate to Eslint

Tags: angular, tslint

I´m updating my aplication to the latest version of angular (13), and when updating to angular 11, i see that [tslint has been deprecated](https://blog.angular.io/version-11-of-angular-now-available-74721b7952f7).

The question is , should i migrate to eslint now or it is best to migrate angular to the latest version before?

Is there any advice on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though TSLint is deprecated for Angular 11 and beyond it doesn't mean it won't work - it works just as fine but might get warnings that it is indeed deprecated. For that reason I suggest that you continue migration fully until you have reached Angular 13 and all related issues are fixed and you can build your project successfully. Otherwise you may end up with too many issues which may make it hard to distinguish if they are migration related or TSLint related... After reaching a stable state in your project, circle back to upgrading and replacing TSLint to ESLint. Follow online guides, it should be hassle free.

E.g: https://medium.com/@bhavinmatariya99/painless-migration-of-tslint-to-eslint-angular-b25da240320c

Comment: Perfect, is just what i need to know.Thanks for the recommendation!